# Asus N550JV Graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have bought a relatively new Asus N550JV notebook, which has two graphic cards and uses a technology called [Optimus](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Optimus/).

This is the hardware information:

```
$ lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Distribution information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux thomas-N550JV 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 18:32:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I want is to use the nvidia card as my default graphics adapter. Is this possible?

What I've tried:

- installing `nvidia-319-updates`
- installing `xserver-xorg-video-intel`
- using the [`ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates?field.series_filter=precise) PPA and installing the above two drivers, independently and together.
- using the [official nvidia 319.49 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.49-driver.html)